# Port full register file from/to a verilog modue

Tags: verilog

How can I port out/in a register file with Verilog (synthesis-able code). At this specific code a generate loop code is not viable due to the architecture of an existing code.

A test code, trying to port to/from my module a dynamic register file, with size based on a parameter.

```
module mux_test (/*AUTOARG*/
   // Outputs
   ro,
   // Inputs
   clk, rst_n, ain, v, din, bias
   ) ;
   parameter D_WIDTH=8;
   parameter A_WIDTH=2;
   localparam N = 1 << A_WIDTH;

   input wire clk, rst_n;
   input wire [A_WIDTH-1:0] ain;
   input wire               v;
   input wire [D_WIDTH-1:0] din;
   input wire [D_WIDTH-1:0] bias[N-1:0];
   output reg [D_WIDTH-1:0] ro[N-1:0];

   wire [D_WIDTH-1:0]       d2s    = din + bias[ain];

   integer                  i;
   always @(posedge clk, negedge rst_n)
     if (!rst_n)
       for(i=0; i<N; i=i+1)
         ro[i] <= 0;
     else if (v)
       ro[ain] <= d2s;

endmodule // mux_test
```

The model-sim gives me the following:

> -- Compiling module mux_test
>
> ** Error: ..../mux_test.v(3): (vlog-2110) Illegal reference to memory "ro".
>
> ** Error: .../mux_test.v(5): (vlog-2110) Illegal reference to net array "bias".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Verilog you cannot have an input or output port with more than one dimension - so you can't declare a 2D array to be an input or output.

Instead you need to pack the array into a single dimension which can be done using a generate loop.

Answer (score 1):

SystemVerilog will allow multi-dimensional ports and should be synthesizable.

```
module mux_test #(
parameter D_WIDTH=8,
parameter A_WIDTH=2 )
(  // Outputs
   output reg [D_WIDTH-1:0] ro[N-1:0],
   // Inputs
   input wire clk, rst_n,
   input wire [A_WIDTH-1:0] ain,
   input wire               v,
   input wire [D_WIDTH-1:0] din,
   input wire [D_WIDTH-1:0] bias[N-1:0]
   );

   localparam N = 1 << A_WIDTH;

   always @(posedge clk, negedge rst_n)
     if (!rst_n)
       for(int i=0; i<N; i=i+1)
         ro[i] <= 0;
     else if (v)
       ro[ain] <= d2s;

endmodule : mux_test
```